# How to retain $scope value once we navigate from one page to another in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers in my file. Whenever I navigate from one page to another page, all the scope values are empty. Here is how I declare my controllers:

```
var app = angular.module('name',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl1',function($scope){});

app.controller('Ctrl2',function($scope){});
```

The above code works fine in one html, but when I navigate to another html, I can't access the $scope values which are in the controller.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you're not supposd to change pages.

Comment: But is there any work around.Will using routes be okay.

Comment: Yes, using routes is the way to go.
Every time you reload the browser everything is reinitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the page wholesale forces the Angular app to completely reload, and this is why you are losing your scope. Obviously, this is less than desirable. What really needs to happen is this:

1. Your base page loads (index.html) and your app lives on this page. It does not contain any content.
2. Your app calls your default route and loads that html partial page in the main ng-view. This route should contain a controller reference that should operate on that view.
3. When you need to load new information on the screen, you load another partial into the ng-view via your route, along with the associated controller.

There are plenty of examples out there to choose from that show how to do this. The stuff from "Year of Moo" comes to mind. Pick one and go with it.